# VScode: avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, archlinux

I just started testing with flutter and dart inspired by Fireship youtube channel, but i have problem with vscode. I don't have any experience with vscode so pls be kind when im dumb :D

Neofetch and some other info:

`````
                   -`                    carrot@CarrotLaptop
                  .o+`                   -------------------
                 `ooo/                   OS: Arch Linux x86_64
                `+oooo:                  Host: 82L7 IdeaPad 5 Pro 14ACN6
               `+oooooo:                 Kernel: 5.15.2-arch1-1
               -+oooooo+:                
             `/:-:++oooo+:               Packages: 954 (pacman)
            `/++++/+++++++:              Shell: bash 5.1.8
           `/++++++++++++++:             Resolution: 1920x1200
          `/+++ooooooooooooo/`           DE: Plasma 5.23.3
         ./ooosssso++osssssso+`          WM: KWin
        .oossssso-````/ossssss+`         Theme: Breeze Light [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3]
       -osssssso.      :ssssssso.        Icons: [Plasma], breeze-dark [GTK2/3]
      :osssssss/        osssso+++.       Terminal: alacritty
     /ossssssss/        +ssssooo/-       CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5800U with Radeon Graphics (16) @ 1
   `/ossssso+/:-        -:/+osssso+-     GPU: AMD ATI 04:00.0 Cezanne
  `+sso+:-`                 `.-/+oso:    Memory: 4527MiB / 13916MiB
 `++:.                           `-/+/
 .`                                 `/

$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12, mixed mode)
`````

So I get this error in vscode when i try to create android emulator: `avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK` ALthought when i run `avdmanager` i got response(java errors) and it shows in the path. My laptop is fairly new so i think it could be some missing software.

The java error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 5 more
```

I have followed this guide https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux and some other stuff from internet and my own acknowledge.

Thank you!

(edit: little bit more info)

Answer (score 1):

According to [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Android#SDK_packages), you need to install [jre8-openjdk](https://archlinux.org/packages/?name=jre8-openjdk) for your avdmanager to work. Afterwards you should [switch your Java environment](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Java#Switching_between_JVM).

Comment: I did try that but still got the same error.
EDIT: Now when i run `avdmanager` in terminal it doesn't give me error.